# Sudoku method and solver

Tags: java, recursion, enums, sudoku, backtracking

I am trying to write a Sudoku solver using back tracking ad recursive, when I finished every thing, my output is just " [] " with nothing in the bracket.
and my expected output should the 3 solution in my tester.

```
 package sudoku;
   import java.util.*;
   public class Grid 
   {
    private int[][] values;


    // Dots in input strings become 0s in values[][].
    //
public Grid(String []rows )
{
    values = new int[9][9];
    for (int j=0; j<9; j++)
    {
        String row = rows[j];
        char[] charray = row.toCharArray();
        for (int i=0; i<9; i++)
        {
            char ch = charray[i];
            if (ch != '.')
                values[j][i] = ch - '0';
        }
    }
}


public Grid(Grid grid) {
    this.grid = grid;
}

public String toString()
{
    String s = "";
    for (int j=0; j<9; j++)
    {
        for (int i=0; i<9; i++)
        {
            int n = values[j][i];
            if (n == 0)
                s += '.';
            else
                s += (char)('0' + n);
        }
        s += "\n";
    }
    return s;
}



//
// Finds an empty member of values[][]. Returns an array list of 9 grids that look like the current grid,
// except the empty member contains 1, 2, 3 .... 9. Returns null if the current grid is full.

//
public ArrayList<Grid> next9Grids(){
    if(this.isFull()) 
    {
        return null;
    } 
    else 
    {
    ArrayList<Grid> grids = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i = 0; i < 9;i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j< 9 ;j++)
        {
            if(values[i][j] == 0) 
            {
                for(int k = 1; k<=9;k++)
                {
                    Grid theGrid = new Grid(this);
                    theGrid.values[i][j] = k;
                    grids.add(theGrid);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return grids;
    }
    }


// Returns true if this grid is legal. A grid is legal if no row, column, or   zone contains
// a repeated 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, or 9.
//
public boolean isLegal()
{
    int row = 0;
    int col = 0;
    int num =0;
     for(  col = 0; col < 9; col++ )
         if( values[row][col] == num )
            return false ;
     for(  row = 0; row < 9; row++ )
         if( values[row][col] == num )
            return false ;
     row = (row / 3) * 3 ;
      col = (col / 3) * 3 ;

      for( int r = 0; r < 3; r++ )
         for( int c = 0; c < 3; c++ )
         if( values[row+r][col+c] == num )
            return false ;
      return true;
}

// Returns true if every cell member of values[][] is a digit from 1-9.
//
public boolean isFull()

{
    int min = 1;
    int max = 9;
    for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++)
    {
      for (int j = 0; j < values[0].length; j++)
      {
        if (values[i][j] < min || values[i][j] > max)
        {
          return false;
        }
      }
    }
    return true;
  }     

// Returns true if x is a Grid and, for every (i,j), 
// x.values[i][j] == this.values[i][j].
//
public boolean equals(Grid that)
{
    Grid x = (Grid)that;
    if (x.equals(this))
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++)
            {
                if (that.values[i][j] == this.values[i][j])
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

}

```
package sudoku;

import java.util.*;


public class Solver 
{
    private Grid                        problem;
    private ArrayList<Grid>             solutions;



public Solver(Grid problem)
{
    this.problem = problem;
    solutions = new ArrayList<Grid>();
}


public ArrayList<Grid> solve()
{
    solutions = new ArrayList<>();
    solveRecurse(problem);
    return solutions;
}


// Standard backtracking recursive solver.
//
private void solveRecurse(Grid grid)
{       
    Evaluation eval = evaluate(grid);

    if (eval == Evaluation.ABANDON)
    {
        return;
    }
    else if (eval == Evaluation.ACCEPT)
    {
        solutions.add(grid);
    }
    else
    {
        ArrayList<Grid> array = grid.next9Grids();
        for (Grid i: array)
        {
        solveRecurse(i);
        // Here if eval == Evaluation.CONTINUE.
        }
    }
}

// Returns Evaluation.ABANDON if the grid is illegal. 
// Returns ACCEPT if the grid is legal and complete.
// Returns CONTINUE if the grid is legal and incomplete.
//
public Evaluation evaluate(Grid grid)
{
    if(!grid.isLegal())
    {
        return Evaluation.ABANDON;
    }
    else if(grid.isLegal() && grid.isFull())
    {
        return Evaluation.ACCEPT;
    }
    else
        return Evaluation.CONTINUE;

}


public ArrayList<Grid> getSolutions()
{
    return solutions;
}


public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Grid g = TestGridSupplier.getPuzzle1();     // or any other puzzle
    Solver solver = new Solver(g);
    solver.solve();
    System.out.println(solver.getSolutions());

    // Print out the solution
```

}

the following is my tester

```
 package sudoku;

   public class TestGridSupplier 
     {

    private final static String[]       PUZZLE_1 =
    {
        "..3.1.5..",
        "8..395..1",
        "15.....27",
        ".8..7..5.",
        "62.9.4.13",
        ".9..2..7.",
        "91.....34",
        "2..748..9",
        "..6.3.2.."     
    };    


    private final static String[]       SOLUTION_1 =
    {
        "463217598",
        "872395641",
        "159486327",
        "384671952",
        "627954813",
        "591823476",
        "918562734",
        "235748169",
        "746139285"
};


static Grid getPuzzle1()        { return new Grid(PUZZLE_1); }
static Grid getSolution1()      { return new Grid(SOLUTION_1); }



private final static String[]        PUZZLE_2 =
{
    ".........",
    "8.1...9.7",
    "..75493..",
    "7..9.2..8",
    "....1....",
    "1..3.8..5",
    "..84312..",
    "2.5...1.9",
    "........."
};     


private final static String[]       SOLUTION_2 =
{
    "439187562",
    "851623947",
    "627549381",
    "763952418",
    "582714693",
    "194368725",
    "978431256",
    "245876139",
    "316295874"
};

static Grid getPuzzle2()        { return new Grid(PUZZLE_2); }
static Grid getSolution2()      { return new Grid(SOLUTION_2); }




private final static String[]        PUZZLE_3 =
{
    ".97..1.6.",
    "2....7..5",
    "....9...3",
    "85.......",
    "..9...5..",
    ".......32",
    "3...7....",
    "5..6....1",
    ".4.1..37."
}; 


private final static String[]       SOLUTION_3 =
{
    "497351268",
    "236847195",
    "185296743",
    "853924617",
    "629713584",
    "714568932",
    "361472859",
    "578639421",
    "942185376"
};


static Grid getPuzzle3()        { return new Grid(PUZZLE_3); }
static Grid getSolution3()      { return new Grid(SOLUTION_3); }


//
// You can use these to test your Grid's evaluate() method.
//
private final static String[]       REJECT_1 =
{
    "11.......",
    ".........",
    ".........",
    ".........",
    ".........",
    ".........",
    ".........",
    ".........",
    "........."
};

private final static String[]       REJECT_2 =
{
    "2........",
    "2........",
    ".........",
    ".........",
    ".........",
    ".........",
    ".........",
    ".........",
    "........."
};

private final static String[]       REJECT_3 =
{
    "3........",
    "..3......",
    ".........",
    ".........",
    ".........",
    ".........",
    ".........",
    ".........",
    "........."
};

private final static String[]       REJECT_4 =
{
    ".........",
    ".........",
    ".........",
    "....4....",
    ".....4...",
    ".........",
    ".........",
    ".........",
    "........."
};

private final static String[]       CONTINUE =
{
    "123456789",
    ".........",
    ".........",
    ".........",
    ".........",
    ".........",
    ".........",
    ".........",
    "........."
};

static Grid getReject1()        { return new Grid(REJECT_1); }
static Grid getReject2()        { return new Grid(REJECT_2); }
static Grid getReject3()        { return new Grid(REJECT_3); }
static Grid getReject4()        { return new Grid(REJECT_4); }
static Grid getContinue()       { return new Grid(CONTINUE); }
static Grid getAccept()         { return getSolution1(); }
```

}

Comment: Maybe it would work better if you had actual code instead of `// TODO Auto-generated constructor stub`?  Or is there really some code there that you forgot to share with us?

Comment: As @user6179968 said: "Perhaps you shouldn't be taking CS46B at San Jose State University if you expect StackOverflow to do your [homework](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7QJIi-5wncoOHp2NXA5WW5zdVk/view) for you ;)"

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to debug the program? 
The reason that you receive an empty solution lies inside isLegal method: 
you initialize num to be 0, and then check if one of the cells equals to 0. Of course, an initial board contains zeros so isLegal always returns false and therefore your program terminates immediately.
As you stated in the comment above isLegal, you should check that the board has no duplication in one of the rows/cols/cubes.
Here, I'll give you the most simple way I Could think of to check that each row has no duplication:

```
    boolean[] rowAppearances;
    for(row = 0; row < 9; row++)
    {
        rowAppearances = new boolean[9];
        for(col = 0; col < 9; col++ )
        {
            if (values[row][col] != 0)
            {
               if(rowAppearances[values[row][col] - 1])
                   return false;
               else
                   rowAppearances[values[row][col] - 1] = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

Best of luck!